# Count number of toggled rows in a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search bar for my table and I filter it as so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        value = '(' + value + ')'
        if (value == '()'){
            value = ""
        }

            $("#table1 tr").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });

        $('#counts').html(String(counter) + " results found")

      });
    });
```

I want to have a counter for that last line that returns the number of filtered results.

Also, removing the parentheses and setting value = "" is very slow.  Is there a way to fix this?  (I added these lines because when you backspaced the search terms no results were coming up since "()" doesn't appear anywhere

Comment: Can you add enough code to reproduce this

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] by clicking the bracket button: `<>` and placing HTML, CSS, and JS/jQ in the Snippet editor.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with the parentheses. Where do you set `counter`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `.filter()`? The callback function doesn't return anything, and you don't assign the result anywhere.

Comment: @Barmar If the sentence is "i like cats" I don't want it to match, I only want it to match "I (like) cats".  I erased where I set counter because it wasnt working at all.  I was hoping you all could help me set  counter

Comment: @Barmar the filter works.  it makes it so only rows containing (word) are displayed

Comment: If everything else works `$("#table1 tr:visible").length` can find the number of visible rows.  I don't understand how setting `value = ''` could be slow

Comment: @IrkenInvader What I mean is that reloading the table with all the rows toggled to being visible is slow.  Is there a way where I can just toggle all rows on? if value == '()'?

Comment: @VinnyChase It looks like you're using `.filter()` when you really mean to use `.each()`. The difference is that `.filter()` returns a new collection of all the elements where the function returns a truthy value. But you're not doing anything with that returned collection.

Comment: It seems like your `if()` is backwards. If the user enters `like`, you set `value` to `(like)`. Then the `if` sets it to `""`.

Comment: "I erased where I set counter because it wasnt working at all." -- The whole point is that you should put that in the question, so we can tell you what you were doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar yeah I just realized.  Thanks

Comment: @IrkenInvader that answer worked perfectly for counting.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the search value is `()` you can use `$("#table1 tr").show();` to make all rows visible.

Use `$("#table1 tr").each` to loop through all rows when toggling their visibility.

After handling the visibility changes to rows you can use `$("#table1 tr:visible").length` to get a count of visible rows.

```
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    value = '(' + value + ')';

    if (value === '()') {
      $("#table1 tr").show();
    } else {
      $("#table1 tr").each(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
    }

    $('#counts').html($("#table1 tr:visible").length + " results found")

  });
```